# Бэкапы сайтов Stack Exchange

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, stackexchange

В эпоху всеобщей коммерциализации нет 100-процентной гарантии, что какой-либо проект не покажется старым или новым владельцам приносящим достаточную прибыль. Тогда многолетний труд тысяч людей пойдёт псу под хвост, как это произошло с сервисами [Яндекс.Ответы](http://www.raskrutka.by/news/20530/) и [«Google Вопросы и Ответы»](https://geektimes.ru/post/224669/), где несмотря ни на что можно было отыскать немало полезной информации. Яндекс и Google вряд ли сильно обеспокоила потеря базы знаний.

Какие меры предприняты в проектах Stack Exchange и русском Stack Overflow в частности на случай закрытия сайтов? Спасибо.

Comment: вероятный дубликат: [Влияние санкций на ruSO](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2361)

Comment: TLDR: качайте дамп https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: @Nofate, в том вопросе говорится о блокировке сайтов по политическим мотивам, у меня — о закрытии по решению собственников. Спасибо.

Comment: @Nofate, а планировалось ли где-нибудь сообществами, какие меры по возрождению будут предприниматься на случай закрытия сайта? Спасибо за ссылку на дамп.

Comment: Политические мотивы или коммерческие - не столь важно. Проблема на выходе будет одна и та же.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Решение, как сказали в комментариях, уже есть: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Обращу внимание, что дампы находятся в ведении **The Internet Acrhive**, а не Stack Exchange. Дампы лицензированы **CC-BY-SA-3.0**. В случае, если владельцы сети сайтов решат закрыться, дампы никуда не денутся. Пока существует Архив Интернета, дампы жить будут. Ну уж а что на американскую компанию сможет надавить наш бешеный принтер — это вообще из области фантастики.

Если же The Internet Acrhive, Stack Exchange, а также все скачавшие дампы вдруг одновременно пропадут, то у вас будут более серьёзные проблемы: выживание во время ядерной зимы среди восставших из земли зомби — это вам не шутки.