# Профилактика вымирания внешних ссылок в сообщениях

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, ссылки

[Серьёзной проблемой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1818/199934) для Stack Overflow и не только является [вымирание ссылок](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA). Предлагаю профилактическую меру для его предотвращения.

Как в проектах Stack Exchange происходит добавление картинок в сообщения: <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd> → <kbd>Оставить ссылку из сети</kbd> → вставляем ссылку на изображение на внешнем сайте, к примеру, https://i.gyazo.com/43793f0c2615d1e44b0ce16c9d3d3642.png , → <kbd>Добавить картинку</kbd> → изображение добавилось в сообщение, но уже под новым URL с сайта Imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpMJN.png .

[image: Тестовая ссылка]

Предлагаю реализовать нечто подобное для ссылок и не на картинки, где в роли Imgur выступал бы сайт [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/web/) (Архив Интернета). Почему именно он:

1. Ресурс с 20-летней историей, уже содержит почти пол-триллиона заархивированных веб-страниц. Cнижается вероятность того, что

   - нагрузка со Stack Overflow окажется для него непомерной,
   - сайт прекратит существование.
2. Между Stack Exchange и Internet Archive [налажено сотрудничество](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/), дампы всех проектов Stack Exchange находятся именно [в ведении Архива Интернета](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2926/199934), вследствие чего, вероятно, проще будет достигнуть договорённостей, если таковые потребуются.

Вместо Архива Интернета можно использовать и другие [сервисы кэширования](http://www.osp.ru/pcworld/2011/06/13009039/).

Как по замыслу будет происходить добавление ссылок в сообщение: <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd> → вставляем нашу ссылку, к примеру, http://www.example.com → <kbd>OK</kbd> → в это время автоматически создаётся снэпшот вида http://web.archive.org/web/20160504104214/http://www.example.com → в сообщение вставляется оригинальная ссылка, поскольку не все архивные одинаково полезны (см. ниже). Периодически по сообщениям проходит бот, чекающий ссылки на валидность, → мёртвые заменяются копиями из Internet Archive. Даже если на Stack Overflow не захотят создавать бота, пользователи сами смогут перейти к резервным копиям веб-страниц при помощи аддонов для наиболее распространённых браузеров, список которых я когда-то [разместил в английской Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Link_rot#External_links). Главное, чтобы архивные копии были — без наших действий далеко не факт, что бот Internet Archive сам создаст их.

Стоит учесть, что резервные копии веб-страниц ввиду своей надёжности предпочтительнее оригиналов, когда содержание веб-страниц — статьи и прочие текстовые материалы. Однако они порой бесполезны, если по ссылкам находится рабочий сервис. Положим, Яндекс по каким-то причинам прекратил своё существование → мы открыли его [резервную копию за 1998 год](http://web.archive.org/web/19981206201051/http://yandex.ru/) → ничего найти в Яндексе по этой ссылке не получится.

Проблемы тем не менее здесь не вижу, разве что небольшая часть страниц заархивируется зря. Если веб-сервис, на который ведёт ссылка, прекратит существование, то потребует правки уже само сообщение со Stack Overflow, содержащее ссылку на него.

Для защиты от спамеров опцию архивация ссылок предлагаю автоматически вводить при достижении какого-либо минимального порога репутации.

---

**UPD**: дополнительно отмечу, что предложение распространяется на любые проекты Stack Exchange, а не только русскоязычный Stack Overflow, отличающийся следующими особенностями:

- На Ru SO негативное отношение к ссылкам в ответах (у меня как минимум 4 возражения, но обсуждать это надо не здесь);
- Информация в сфере IT подвержена быстрому устареванию, почему для неё, возможно, и полезен тот «естественный отбор» в социал-дарвинистской трактовке термина, о котором [говорил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2990/199934) ув-мый Nick Volynkin.

Однако другие проекты могут и не обладать вышеперечисленными особенностями. Примеры:

- я не обращаюсь к проекту Stack Exchange «Русский язык» как раз [из-за недостаточного в нём количества ссылок на авторитетные источники](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29408189#29408189).
- При работе с историческими материалами за неимением более современных источников мне часто приходится устремлять взор на [Энциклопедический словарь Брокгауза и Ефрона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%95%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) 100-летней давности.

Comment: Давайте использовать в ссылках нейтральные сайты, а не собственные страницы. Иначе это выглядит как скрытая реклама.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ОК. Спасибо.

Answer (score 11):

Вы предлагаете внедрить промежуточный костыль, который будет спасать вымирающие ссылки. Однако, он же будет их и хоронить.

Предположим, я прикладываю к ответу ссылку на документацию, которая более полно раскрывает мой ответ. Проходит три года, продукт существенно обновляется и вместе с ним обновляется документация. Какие-то из использованных мной инструментов устарели, какие-то ограничения теперь сняты, для чего-то появилось более удачное решение.

Однако, ссылка по-прежнему ведёт на страницу трехлетней давности. Да, она наверняка продолжает существовать в архиве. Полезна ли она? Нет, она безнадежно устарела. Она представляет ценность только для археологов и путешественников во времени, которые почему-то вынуждены использовать устаревшую версию продукта.

Чтобы попасть на страницу настоящей документации, мне теперь нужно вручную выдрать из адреса архивную часть и перейти на настоящий сайт. Энергией гнева, вырабатываемого пользователями при таких манипуляциях со ссылками, можно будет запитать энергосеть небольшой страны.

Ссылки должны вымирать. Это естественный отбор информации. Если закрылся какой-то бложек, ничего страшного - мы ведь разместили всю существенную информацию в самом ответе. А если не разместили и ответ целиком опирается на ссылки, а ссылки вымерли - то и ответ должен умереть вместе с ними. Это был плохой ответ.

Собственно, поэтому ответы-ссылки сразу скидываются со скалы. Они несамодостаточны и проиграют в естественном отборе. А полные ответы выиграют. Давайте не будем препятствовать естественному отбору.

Comment: > Чтобы попасть на страницу настоящей документации, мне теперь нужно вручную выдрать из адреса архивную часть и перейти на настоящий сайт. — см. «в сообщение вставляется оригинальная ссылка, поскольку не все архивные одинаково полезны». Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, в чем тогда смысл архивной ссылки, если все равно **должна** быть ссылка начальная, которая испортится? Котлетка!

Comment: @Grundy, в том, что у оригинальной ссылки будет архивная копия, которую можно будет просмотреть, если оригинальная станет мёртвой. В самом предложении-вопросе описал это. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, тогда зачем смотреть устаревшие данные, если надо перейти на настоящий сайт? просто дублирование ссылки ради дублирования? Конфетка.

Comment: @Grundy, предлагается просто иметь архив для любой ссылки на случай, если она вымрет. Т. е. если пользователь открывает ссылку, а там пустота, он берёт и откврывает сохранённую копию вместо неё.

Answer (score 8):

Это решение все равно предполагает, что суть ответа будет не в теле ответа, а где-то черт знает где, в непонятно какой форме.

Суть SO - получение прямого ответа. А не ссылки на ответ.

Это сайт вопросов и ответов, а не каталог ссылок.

Предлагаю

- правила не менять
- ответы-ссылки все так же считать низкокачественными
- копирование ответов по ссылкам прямо в тело ответа считать добром (даже в тело нового ответа, создание выжимки из полотна текста по ссылке - вполне так работа)

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите, где я предлагал: **[1]** — менять правила, **[2]** — не считать ответы-ссылки низкокачественными. Речь идёт о любых ответах,  содержащих ссылки, а не только ответах-ссылках. Спасибо.

Comment: [Пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458486/199934) Вашего же ответа, содержащего внешние ссылки. Ссылка на страницу, содержащую онлайн-версию книги [PHP:правильный путь](http://phptherightway.ru/) без архивирования в любой момент может оказаться мёртвой. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных списки литературы по тэгу `книги` - особая категория вопросов. Ответы к ним поддерживаются актуальными силами сообщества.

Comment: @СашаЧерных кроткая предыстория этого ответа - после переезда с хэшкода вопросы "что почитать" внезапно стали оффтопиком (хотя регулярно задавались, и на них массово давались ответы-ссылки), при попытке их закрыть [зашкалило нытье](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/162/) и вопросы с книгами решили оставить, но именно общие, и по одному на технологии (лично я был против). Тот, на который вы привели ссылку - я собрал с пачки существующих вопросов по PHP, и мое имя там стоит только из-за того, что я вписал 84% содержимого ответа.

Comment: @PashaPash вот так вы нечаянно стали специалистом по PHP. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin черное пятно в моей биографии

Comment: @СашаЧерных если в ответе ссылка приведена лишь как дополнение - то пусть устаревает, мы же не википедия, где нужны АИ и прочие [источник не указан 21 день].

Comment: @PashaPash пройдут годы, ещё и знаков за него надают. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin медные уже получил, и за вопрос, и за ответ :)

Comment: @PashaPash, почему здесь не нужны АИ? я всегда, пусть даже в диалогах в Одноклассниках, привык указывать ссылки на авторитетные источники, подтверждающие мои слова. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных текущий онтопик на SO требует объективно верных ответов. Т.е. таких, которые верны *сами по себе*, а не "выглядят верными потому что-то авторитетный где-то там что-то написал". Кусок кода не нужно подтверждать ссылкой - он или работает, или нет. Собственно, поэтому на сайте и существует причина закрытия "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ".

Answer (score 4):

В теории, вы можете вставлять ссылки такого вида: [ссылка](http://www.example.com)<sup>[[архив]](http://web.archive.org/web/20160504104214/http://www.example.com)</sup>

таким образом:

```
[ссылка](http://www.example.com)<sup>[[архив]]( http://web.archive.org/web/20160504104214/http://www.example.com)</sup>
```

И можно даже написать под это юзерскрипт, меняющий поведение кнопки <kbd>Гиперссылка</kbd>.

Но я сильно подозреваю, что без консенсуса сообщества такие ссылки будут всех раздражать.

Comment: Вручную всё равно придётся архивировать ссылку. Спасибо.